# How do I make a video continuously stream to a TKinter frame in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, video, video-streaming

Currently, I'm using tkvideoutils to stream webcam footage to a frame on tkinter.

You can find the source code for tkvideoutils [here](https://github.com/wsarce/tkVideoUtils/blob/main/tkvideoutils/tkvideoutils.py).

I'm trying to create a feature where if I press the space bar once, it starts saving the video, and if I press it again, it writes the video to a file called "video.mp4". However, when I press the space bar a second time, the streaming of the webcam footage freezes for a couple of seconds. Is there any way to get around that?

self.__video_display_thread() seems to be a thread in tkvideoutils that only runs when self.recording is true. So it only displays when the video is being recorded for storage. This isn't what I want, so I replaced the `while self.recording` to `while true`. Nevertheless, the webcam footage still freezes.

I also tried to use the multiprocessing library to run that thread (I was guessing that I was running into some issue with regards to the Global Interpreter Lock) but that doesn't work since tkinter objects cannot be pickled.

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideoutils import VideoRecorder


class Master_UI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("project")
        self.master.geometry("640x600")
        self.io_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.io_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, side=BOTTOM)
        # Bind key press event to the window
        root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.on_key_press)
        # first number is start_recording enabled or not, second is end_recording enabled or not, and last is submit enabled or not
        self.button_state = "100"
        # initiate the dialogue model instance

        video_sources = VideoRecorder.get_video_sources()
        audio_sources = VideoRecorder.get_audio_sources()
        print(video_sources, audio_sources)

        self.ffmpeg_exe = r'\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
        self.video_path = 'video.mp4'
        self.audio_path = 'recorded_audio.wav'
        self.merged_path = 'video.mp4'
        self.recording_label = Label(self.io_frame, text="")
        self.recording_label.pack()
        if video_sources:
            if self.video_path:
                # read video to display on label
                self.recording = VideoRecorder(video_source=video_sources[0], audio_source=audio_sources[1],
                                               video_path=self.video_path, audio_path=self.audio_path, fps=30,
                                               label=self.recording_label,
                                               size=(300, 300))
                self.recording.start_playback()

        self.is_recording = False

    def merge_sources(self):
        self.recording.stop_playback()
        if self.recording.merge_sources(self.merged_path, self.ffmpeg_exe, delete_file=False):
            print("Sources merged!")
        else:
            print("Something went wrong")
        self.recording.start_playback()

    # Function to start recording audio
    def start_recording(self):
        self.button_state = "010"
        self.recording.start_recording()
        self.is_recording = True

        print("Recording started...")

    # Function to stop recording audio
    def stop_recording(self):
        # Stop the audio stream
        self.is_recording = False
        self.merge_sources()
        self.button_state = "101"
        self.submit()
        print("Recording stopped.")

    # Function to handle the submit button click
    def submit(self):
        # disables submitting
        self.button_state = "100"

        with open(self.audio_path, "rb") as audio_file:
            content = audio_file.read()

    # Function to handle key press events
    def on_key_press(self, event):
        if event.char == ' ':
            if self.button_state[0] == '1':
                self.start_recording()
            elif self.button_state[1] == '1':
                self.stop_recording()
        elif event.char == 's':
            if self.button_state[2] == '1':
                self.submit()


def on_closing():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Master_UI(root)

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()
```

If anyone has a solution that stops (or reduces) the amount of time the webcam is frozen, please let me know!

Also, if there is anything that is unclear, I'd be happy to clear up any questions :).